# Ошибка dpkg при установке nodejs-legacy: попытка перезаписать файл

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

Перепробовал все, были попытки с установленным и без nodejs

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
...
НОВЫЕ пакеты, которые будут установлены:
nodejs nodejs-legacy rlwrap
...
Unpacking nodejs-legacy (0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive 
/var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs legacy_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
попытка перезаписать «/usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz», который уже имеется 
в пакете nodejs 0.10.37-1chl1~trusty1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. для начала я бы порекомендовал удалить установленный явно не из репозитория дистрибутива пакет *nodejs* (для надёжности и *nodejs-legacy*):

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get remove nodejs nodejs-legacy
   ```
2. судя по версии (0.10.37-1chl1~trusty1) и по выдаче *google* на поиск этой строки, пакет был установлен из какого-то `ubuntuupdate.org`. если вы его (репозиторий) прописали в `/etc/apt/sources.list*`, то закомментируйте (добавив символ `#` в начало **всех** незакомментированных строк, где он встретится) или удалите **все** упоминания этого репозитория. найти файлы, в которых он прописан, можно, например, с помощью программы `grep`:

   ```
   $ grep -lir ubuntuupdates.org /etc/atp/sources.list*
   ```
3. теперь следует обновить список пакетов:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. и можно попробовать установить требующийся вам пакет:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
   ```

Comment: Следовал вашим указаниям, все прошло успешно. Но упоминаний про  ubuntuupdate.org нигде не нашел. А еще удалил в каталоге etc/apt/sources.list.d/ файлы с упоминанием nodejs. Спасибо вам огромное за помошь!

Comment: значит, либо пакеты ставились «вручную» (скачаны файлы и установлены программой `dpkg`), либо упоминания были удалены раньше. на всякий случай: не забывайте обновлять список пакетов (`sudo apt-get update`) после правки файлов `/etc/apt/sources.list*` **и** перед установкой пакетов (командой `sudo apt-get install ...`).